# Authorize an application after installation

Tags: bigcommerce

When an user installs an application BigCommerce will make a call to your application at `/auth?code=qr6h3thvbvag2ffq&scope=store_v2_orders&context=stores/g5cd38` with these parameters.

Using that you can exchange the temporary code with an access token, and this happens only when an user installs the application.

Is there a way to get an access token after an application is installed ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you'd need to obtain a new access token if you have already obtained one on install?

Comment: @Alyss in case somehow I loose them or if they expire.

Comment: If you lose them, the app has to be reinstalled. They shouldn't expire.

Comment: @Alyss so in case I loose them I should message users to uninstall the application and install it again, right ?